# Something went wrong Failed to load schema for "graphql/"

Tags: node.js, graphql

After I run command `yarn gen` it is giving me this error :

> Something went wrong Failed to load schema for "graphql/" Failed to
> load schema from http://localhost:1337/graphql:
>
> fetch failed TypeError: fetch failed at Object.processResponse
> (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5570:34) at
> node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5896:42 at
> node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7 at
> AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9) at
> AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
>
> GraphQL Code Generator supports:
>
> - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
> - Introspection JSON File
> - URL of GraphQL endpoint
> - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)
> - String in config file
>
> Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.

here is my homepage.graphql

```
query HomePage {
  homePage {
    data {
      attributes {
        sections {
          ... on ComponentCommonHeader {
            id
            Text
            ButtonText
            ButtonLink
          }
          ... on ComponentCommonCarousel {
            id
            Item
          }
          ... on ComponentCommonTwoColumnBlock {
            id
            TitleText
            Description
            ButtonText
            ButtonUrl
            ImagePosition
            Image
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my graphql.config.yml:

```
overwrite: true
schema:
  - http://localhost:1337/graphql
documents: "graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  graphql/types.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
  graphql/:
    preset: near-operation-file
    presetConfig:
      extension: .generated.tsx
      baseTypesPath: types.ts
    plugins:
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
    config:
      withHooks: true
```

Comment: Is your backend server with your graphql endpoint running? Is the port and url correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this and fixed it by replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. Other solution that you may want to try is to delete `node_modules` and  `package-lock.json` and to reinstall dependencies.